# What is the item Professor Sycamore is referring to after you meet him in Couriway Town?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

After you fight Professor Sycamore in Couriway Town he says there is an item hidden in the town. Of course there are several but looking at [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Couriway_Town) none of the items listed seem especially notable besides the Gyaradosite which you can't get until after you beat the Elite 4 anyway (as far as I have heard).

So does anybody know which one is Sycamore's 'special' present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read this answer on [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/696960-pokemon-y/answers?qid=359081). Check it out.

> More accurate location, if you stand inbetween the two benches to the right of her, take  one step south, one step east, and then turn around, you'll find a written message seemingly carved into the floor. It's not a hidden item, so it wont get picked up by the  dowsing machine.

Answer (score -2):

it is in couriway town at the train station in between the two benchs I don't know what it means but that is the treasure for some reason.